# Figure caption overlapping with minipages

Tags: captions, minipage

I'm using `minipage` to define three images side by side.

However, the captions of those images are overlapping instead of breaking lines according to each minipage.

[image]

Following is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/briefing-structure.png}
    \caption{Overview of each part that compose the briefings structure.}
    \label{fig:briefings_structure}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/briefing-informationdesign.png}
    \caption{Overview of the briefings and the elements of Design Information and Grids \cite{Tondreau2011}}
    \label{fig:information_design}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/briefing-gestalt.png}
    \caption{Overview of the briefings and the elements of gestalt theory \cite{Lupton2015}}
    \label{fig:briefings_gestalt}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
```

Does anybody know what can be done?

UPDATE:

The document is composed by many files, but here is part of the header of the main tex file:

```
\documentclass[en,twoside,onehalfspacing,qual]{risethesis}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

\restylefloat*{figure}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\captionsetup[table]{position=top,justification=centering,width=.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf,font=small}
%for code un-comment it
%\captionsetup[lstlisting]{position=top,justification=centering,width=.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf,font=small}
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,justification=centering,width=.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf,font=small}

%% Change the following pdf author attribute name to your name.
\usepackage[linkcolor=black,
            citecolor=blue,
            urlcolor=black,
            colorlinks,
            pdfpagelabels,
            pdftitle={Rise Thesis Template (ABNT)},
            pdfauthor={Rise Thesis Template (ABNT)}]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the problem was in the following line:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,justification=centering,width=.85\textwidth,labelfont=bf,font=small}
```

It has changed the setup of captions. After commenting that line, everything worked just fine.

Comment: To be more specific, the problematic part is just `width=.85\textwidth` since this sets the width of caption to 85% of the `\textwidth` when entering a `figure` environment. If you want a margin for your captions, better use `margin=...` or something like `calcwidth=.85\linewidth`.

Answer (score 2):

Please always post a full document that reproduces the problem, which here is caused by some code that you have not posted. by default you get:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/briefing-structure.png}
    \caption{Overview of each part that compose the briefings structure.}
    \label{fig:briefings_structure}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/briefing-informationdesign.png}
    \caption{Overview of the briefings and the elements of Design Information and Grids \cite{Tondreau2011}}
    \label{fig:information_design}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/briefing-gestalt.png}
    \caption{Overview of the briefings and the elements of gestalt theory \cite{Lupton2015}}
    \label{fig:briefings_gestalt}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the document os composed by many files, I update the post with part of the header of the main tex file. Hope it is enough.

Comment: @Bruno no sorry it is not enough, you have the file causing the problem so you should be able to easily make a complete test document. Just start with the one I posted and add stuff until it breaks, or start from a copy of yours and delete stuff until it is small enough to post.